# How to get excel to divide a figure based on 3 conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the data below and what I want to do is:

- Take the salary in column F and divide it into two columns (G&H, which are two projects).
- The two columns are either 50% or 100% of the cost. So could sometimes be £0.00
- There is a Key to the right showing if a person works on either column 100% or 50% between the two projects.

Can anyone help me please?

[image]

I've tried to use multiple formulas such as sumif lookup and such but can't quite get it right. I want to divide the time spend on either project whether that is 50% or 100%

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Particularly what this key looks like. And also an example of what your expected result is.

Comment: And let us know what you have tried, this may be solved with a simple `IF` statement

Comment: Hi, apologies I have added an image now. I tried an IF statement but maybe I'm just doing it wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really said how the Key shows if a person works on either column 100% or 50%, so I have assumed that it shows the % time spent on project 1, and the remaining time is spent on Project 2.

In which case, in order to calculate the Project 1 column, you can multiply the salary by the key:

[image]

Then to calculate the Project 2 column, you could take the total salary and subtract the Project 1 column:

[image]

If my assumption is wrong, please clarify with sample data and a key, and I will be happy to update my answer.

***EDIT - In response to updated question***

I would suggest you change your key as it could be made simpler.
However, I am going to go ahead and assume that isn't possible.

You will need to use an INDEX/MATCH formula to lookup which projects a person has been working on and set the % to multiply the salary by appropriately:

[image]

```
=F5
*
IF(INDEX($K$4:$K$7,MATCH(B5,$J$4:$J$7,0))="Prog1",1,
IF(INDEX($K$4:$K$7,MATCH(B5,$J$4:$J$7,0))="Prog2",0,
0.5))
```

This takes the salary on each row and multiplies it by 0, 0.5, or 1. Depending upon whether the text in the Programme column of the key says "Prog1", or "prog2", or something else.

Comment: Hi, apologies I have added an image to the question now. Thank you (: